# How do I create a .pl file in prolog that I can import all of my predicates in?

Tags: prolog, homebrew, predicate

It looks like I need to create a .pl file with all of my predicates that I can use to write programs with.

I am using homebrew in my mac terminal because I really did not like the Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.26 interface that is recommended for El Captian. 
I was able to do it in windows a few years back but did not get to far after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure what you're asking.  A .pl file is a text file with Prolog code in it.  Just use any text editor.